# Instrumentation getobjectsize in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, pom.xml, manifest, instrumentation

I am writing a spring-boot application, where I have some rest services, I want to measure the size of my incoming payload, and want to use I want to Instrumentation.

Please find my code below:

```java
public class Sizeof {
    private static Instrumentation instrumentation;
    
    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
        System.out.println("inisde ::: args ::: " + args + " :::: inst :::: " + inst);
        instrumentation = inst;
    }
    
    public static long sizeof(Object o) {
        return instrumentation.getObjectSize(o);
    }
}
```

Controller class:

```java
@RestController
public class FileController {

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @PostMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(@RequestParam("emps") Employee[] emps) {
        System.out.println("Size :::: " + Sizeof.sizeof(file));
        return new ResponseEntity<>("OK ", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

manifest entry in pom.xml

```xml
<build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <finalName>are-agent</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Premain-Class>com.sample.component.Sizeof</Premain-Class>
                            <Can-Redefine-Classes>false</Can-Redefine-Classes>
                            <Can-Retransform-Classes>true</Can-Retransform-Classes>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

but my `premain` method is not getting invoked, can you please help

Comment: Maybe you simply forgot to start the JVM with `java -javaagent:/path/to/pre-agent.jar ...`. Oh, and I do hope that your agent is in a separate Maven module and not in the same one as the application it is meant to instrument, which is what it looks like here or at least you did not explain otherwise.

Comment: I am using it in a spring boot application, and cannot use `java -javaagent:/path/to/pre-agent.jar ...`

Comment: The fact that you use Spring Boot does not prohibit you from using a Java agent. Spring even documents how to do that, e.g. if you want to use native AspectJ instead of Spring AOP within Spring applications. So that is not a reason at all. Are there any other ones? Besides, why would you produce a Java agent if you say you cannot use it? It sounds quite contradictory to me.

Comment: Speaking of AOP, maybe Spring AOP or an advisor or interceptor would be a better solution for your problem than a Java agent anyway. Possible we are dealing with an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898) here. You are so focused on **how** you think you ought to solve your problem instead of thinking about **what** you want to do. Maybe your choice of tool is just not right. You can use a Java agent to do what you want. no doubt. But it might be the most complicated way to solve your problem and simpler ones exist.

Comment: This method won’t give you “the size of my incoming payload”, as it will only return the *shallow* size of an object. In other words, it’s not even capable of telling you, how much memory a string consumes (or a BigInteger), not to speak of an entity consisting of several properties having reference types (including strings and other composed types). You’d need to recursively traverse the object structure, to sum up all sizes, but the result might be far away from the size of the *serialized* data.

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala how to resolved your pblm ? I am looking for solution of similar pblm